# GridView Column Vs. DataList Column

Tags: asp.net, gridview, datalist, itemtemplate, templatefield

In GridView we write `ItemTemplate` in `TemplateField` and why do not write `TemplateField` in DataList.

**GridView:**

```
    <asp:TemplateField>
        <ItemTemplate>
            .......
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

**DataList:**

```
    <ItemTemplate>
        .......
    </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

**DataList** and **GridView** are different controls and they have different syntax.

**GridView** is more "powerfull" control. It can have such column types like **BoundField**, **CommandField**, **TemplateField**, etc.

There are large differences between these controls.

PS: You forgot **Columns** tag at **GridView** syntax in your question.